# 'would not let' vs 'would not have let'

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

What is the difference between these two sentences?

> 1) If I were you I would not **have** let him go unhurt.
>
> 2) If I were you I would not let him go unhurt.

Comment: What *specifically* confuses you here? You've changed (implied past) ***have let*** to (implied future) ***have***. But you've also expanded ***wouldn't*** to ***would not*** - is that relevant?.

Comment: If it's not relevant, you should be more careful typing the sentences that you want us to explain. I'd hate to have someone invest time explaining something that you weren't concerned about simply because of your carelessness.

Comment: I do understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example one is referring to an event that happened before the sentence was spoken:

> If I were you, I would not have let him go unhurt (yesterday).

Example two could be referring to present or future:

> If I were you, I would not let him go unhurt (now).
>
> If I were you, I would not let him go unhurt (tomorrow).